# Adding the trace listener in webroles.cs as the WebRole process is not configured by the web.config

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

The below code is working without any problems with azure sdk 2.3 -
WebRole.cs :
Trace.Listeners.Add(new DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());

Also, the following is logged in the web.config file :

But since I upgraded the azure sdk to 2.5, WebRole.cs code (as written above) started throwing error.

I observed that this is happening due to the below reason -
In Azure SDK 2.3 : DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener inherits from TraceListener
In Azure SDK 2.5 : DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener inherits from Microsoft.Cis.Eventing.Listeners.RDEventMonitoringAgentListener

Can someone please suggest a solution for this problem

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own wrapper class that inherits from the abstract class TraceListener. e.g.:

```
public class MyTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private readonly DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener _traceListener= new DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener();

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        _traceListener.Write(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        _traceListener.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

You can then add this listener in the traditional way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new MyTracelistener());
```

**Update:** I found that the real cause of this issue is not that DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener inherits from a different class, but that you might be missing a reference to *MonAgentListener*. You should be able to add a reference to this DLL via the "Add Reference" dialog for your project. After I added that Assembly, I could add DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener as a TraceListener object without the wrapper, i.e.

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
```